# emacs syntax highlighting for jags / bugs

Tags: jags

Are there packages to color-highlight jags amd bugs model files? I have ESS installed, but it doesn't seem to recognize .bug files or jags/bugs syntax out of the box.

Comment: Did you try `M-x ess-jags-mode` on your model file? (or see ESS help on how to [handle JAGS file](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS_0028JAGS_0029_002d_002dModel-files))

Comment: Strange, that command is undefined for me, was it added in a very recent version of ess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Syntax highlighting

I'm using ESS 5.14 (from ELPA) and syntax highlighting or smart underscore works fine for me with GNU Emacs 24.1.1. If you want to highlight a given file, you can try `M-x ess-jags-mode` or add a hook to highlight JAGS file each time, e.g.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jag\\'" . jags-mode))
```

However, that is not really needed since you can simply

```
(require 'ess-jags-d)
```

in your `.emacs`. There's a corresponding mode for BUGS file. This file was already included in earlier release (at least 5.13), and it comes with the corresponding `auto-mode-alist` (for `"\\.[jJ][aA][gG]\\'"` extension).
(Please note that there seems to exist [subtle issue](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ess.general/5942) with using both JAGS and BUGS, but I can't tell more because I only use JAGS.)

### Running command file

If you want to stick with Emacs for running JAGS (i.e., instead of [rjags](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjags/index.html) or other R interfaces to JAGS/BUGS), there's only one command to know:
As described in the [ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS_0028JAGS_0029_002d_002dCommand-files), when working on a command file, `C-c C-c` should create a `.jmd` file, and then `C-c C-c`'ing again should submit this command file to Emacs `*shell*` (in a new buffer), and call `jags` in batch mode. Internally, this command is binded to a 'Next Action' instruction (`ess-*-next-action`). For example, using the mice data that comes with JAGS sample files, you should get a `mice.jmd` that looks like that:

```
model in "mice.jag"
data in "mice.jdt"
compile, nchains(1)
parameters in "mice.in1", chain(1)
initialize
update 10000
update 10000
#
parameters to "mice.to1", chain(1)
coda \*, stem("mice")
system rm -f mice.ind
system ln -s miceindex.txt mice.ind
system rm -f mice1.out
system ln -s micechain1.txt mice1.out
exit
Local Variables:
ess-jags-chains:1
ess-jags-command:"jags"
End:
```

Be careful with default filenames! Here, data are assumed to be in file `mice.jdt` and initial values for parameters in `mice.in1`. You can change this in the Emacs buffer if you want, as well as modify the number of chains to use.